# Grid system can't locate with navbar

Tags: css, navbar, grid-system

I have some question with navbar and grid system.

Q1.grid system

I make two 100% height navbar on left and right , but  the center text seems locate on the left :0 ,and the left navbar overlaps it.

Here's a link to my code.

[enter link description here](http://jsfiddle.net/pjBzY/297/)

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 0;
}

[class*="col-"] {
    float: left;
}

.col-1 {
    width: 4.16%;
}
.col-2 {
    width: 8.33%;
}
.col-3 {
    width: 12.5%;
}
.col-4 {
    width: 16.66%;
}
.col-5 {
    width: 20.83%;
}
.col-6 {
    width: 25%;
}
.col-7 {
    width: 29.16;
}
.col-8 {
    width: 33.33%;
}
.col-9 {
    width: 37.5%;
}
.col-10 {
    width: 41.66%;
}
.col-11 {
    width: 45.83%;
}
.col-12 {
    width: 50%;
}
.col-13 {
    width: 54.16%;
}
.col-14 {
    width: 58.33%;
}
.col-15 {
    width: 62.5%;
}
.col-16 {
    width: 66.66%;
}
.col-17 {
    width: 70.83%;
}
.col-18 {
    width: 75%;
}
.col-19 {
    width: 79.16%;
}
.col-20 {
    width: 83.33%;
}
.col-21 {
    width: 87.5%;
}
.col-22 {
    width: 91.66%;
}
.col-23 {
    width: 95.83%;
}
.col-24 {
    width: 100%;
}

.navbar-fixed-top {
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    right: 0;
    left: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
    z-index: 1030;
}
ul {

    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: #1c2333;
    clear: both;
}
li {
    float: left;
    border: 1 white dashed;
    line-height: 50px;
}
li:last-child {
    border-right: none;
}
li a {
    height: 57px;
    width: 60px;
    display: block;
    color: #8fa5be;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 10px 10px;
    text-decoration: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    overflow: visible;

    border-style: solid transparent;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.active, li a:hover {
    color: #ffffff;
    background-color: #3099f5;
}

/*--*/
.nv{
  position:fixed;
  display: flex;
  width:4.16%;
  height: 100%;
}

.nvr {
    display: flex;
    position: fixed;
    height: 100%;
    width: 80px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
    margin: 0;
}


.height-100 {
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="row navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-24">
                <ul>
                    <li><a class="active">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
                    <li style="float:right"><a class="active" href="#about">hom</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-1">
                <!--
            <div class="nv height-100">
                <ul>
                    <li><a>hom</a></li>
                    <li><a class="active" href="#home">hom</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
          -->
                <div class="nv">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#home">Left</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Cont</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>



            <div class="col-22">
                whatever ,here just the testing text.
            </div>
                <!--
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#home">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
        <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
-->



            <div class="col-1">
                <div class="nv">
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#home">Right</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#news">News</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#contact">Cont</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>
```

The picture shows what I want .
[What I actually want .](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwtm1.png)

Q2.
How can I make the same text block size with top and both side ?

At the full screen , they have the same size , but I want to know how to do. 
Thank you very much.